# Android state file does not find dpi dependent drawable

Tags: android

I have a state file for buttons which worked fine until I put drawables into `res/drawable-mdpi`.
I had only drawable in `res/drawable-hdpi` but I want the app to work on all displays.

The state file is placed in `res/drawable` as I read it on some websites.
That way it is also done by google with the standard drawables but Ecplise keeps telling me that it can't find `drawable with value @drawable/button_normal`.
The drawables are definitely at their places.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...there was nothing wrong with the code, drawables were not ok.
I made them again, 9-patched them and voilà: no comments by eclipse.
Sorry for wasting place for this.

Answer (score 0):

make a folder drawable inside res and put ya pics into that folder. and you can refer to them as

```
android:background="@drawable/oscar"
```